# Mudar formato date e date time no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Não quero código para enviar a data convertida para o MySQL, quero saber se é possível a data aparecer como `09/05/2018 09:59:54` ao invés de `2018-05-09 09:59:54`.

É possível mudar isso em alguma configuração?

Comment: há realmente a necessidade de ser salva assim? Não seria melhor formatar apenas para exibição?

Comment: @WeesSmith eu acho que quando ele disse "não quero código para enviar a data convertida", ele quis dizer que não quer salvar, mas apenas exibir convertido (e isso é a coisa mais certa a se fazer mesmo)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, to viajando aqui kkkkk

Comment: Tipo eu preciso converter para receber no banco de dados e depois converter para exibir, então se essa operação for possível são alguns códigos a menos e fica mais padronizado na DB

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse artigo: [configurar o MySQL para exibir datas em português](https://elias.praciano.com/2015/06/como-configurar-o-mysql-para-exibir-datas-em-portugues/) Creio que pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, concordo com o @Wallace que o ideal é tratar na aplicação, mas como você pediu, a resposta seria:

1. **Não dá pra mudar nativamente**
2. Mas dá pra mudar a língua das funções que mostram por extenso

A documentação é sua amiga:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html

A linguagem da data é controlado pela variável `lc_time_names`, mas **ISSO NÂO MUDA O FORMATO ISO**, só a lingua!

Exemplo retirado do manual:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2010-01-01','%W %a %M %b');
+-----------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('2010-01-01','%W %a %M %b') |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Friday Fri January Jan                  |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET lc_time_names = 'es_MX';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@lc_time_names;
+-----------------+
| @@lc_time_names |
+-----------------+
| es_MX           |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DAYNAME('2010-01-01'), MONTHNAME('2010-01-01');
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| DAYNAME('2010-01-01') | MONTHNAME('2010-01-01') |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| viernes               | enero                   |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

Se for pelo PHP, você pode usar a data do banco e exibir ela no formato desejado:

```
$date = new DateTime($data_do_banco);

echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Mas é possível também fazer isso pelo select:

```
 SELECT id, nome, DATE_FORMAT(data, "%d/%m/%Y H%/%i/%S") as data_formatada FROM table
```

Comment: eu quero mudar o formato dentro do banco

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais pra que? qual é a necessidade disso? Tem que ter um motivo para querer uma data fora do formato do Mysql

Comment: Não basta apenas converter a exibição, amigo? Ou você quer mudar a forma que o PHPMYADMIN exibe a data? [se for esse último, deveria ter especificado isso na pergunta]

Comment: Para não precisar ficar convertendo as datas, trabalho com muitos campos de datas e isso é chato

Comment: Isso quero mudar a forma que o PHPMYADMIN exibe a data!

Comment: Jovem, aí depende da forma que você está trabalhando. Eu trabalho com Laravel por exemplo, e não converto nada que está no banco. Eu deixo o Model formatando a data por padrão num formato brasileiro.

Comment: então eu estou convertendo assim $var->format("Y-m-d") então mas queria poder enviar o valor direto

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais você usa "php na mão" ou usa algum framework?

Comment: Observação: Mudar a data de exibição no PHPMYADMIN não vai mudar a data no seu sistema. O que você deve fazer é uma padronização e não uma forçação de barra! Você deve padronizar com funções ou configurações o formato desejado.

Comment: Dado o +1, só postei uma complementação pras funções que usam extenso.